# ¿Cómo poner un html dentro de otro html?

Tags: html

Tiene que ser como el de los articulos de el periodico marca o sport [aqui link](http://www.marca.com/futbol/atletico/2017/10/13/59dfcfbce5fdea01138b4682.html)

es como una pagina web con una url y cuando ya esta terminando empieza la otra y cambia la url. Me han comentado que es con una tecnica nueva. Espero que me podais ayudar y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Realmente no esta anidado, simplemente conforme bajas el scrool cambia el contenido.

Comment: Si, efectivamente. Cuando vas bajando haciendo scrool cambia de url. Sabes como hacerlo??